# Calling function from another controller

Tags: symfony

I have two controllers

DefaultController

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
```

ApiController

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    public function getCategoryAction()
    {
```

Now I want to call getCategoryAction from my DefaultController.

Is it impossible or how can I make it?

Comment: What do you mean by "call" getCategoryAction. Do you just want to return the same response/template or process the returned data further afterwards ?

Comment: getCategoryAction shows categoryList.xml ( because this controller is for API usage). So,I want to use categoryList.xml in indexAction()

Comment: can you be more specific on what you mean in terms of "use it" ? do you want to do something with it (like read it and change something) or just return the same xml as the API action ?

Comment: I would like to parse the xml and use data in html.

Answer (score 1):

There is [forwarding](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding) in Symfony2. So, you could do sth like that:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // @var Response $categoryListResponse
        $categoryListResponse = $this->forward('YourBundle:Api:getCategory');
        // ... further modify the response or return it directly
        return $categoryListResponse;
    }
}
```

Where `$categoryListResponse` is [Response](http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Response.html) type and represents an HTTP response. So you could `$categoryListResponse->getContent()` from this response.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure controller as a service and then use

```
$this->forward('controller.service.name')->methodOnTheController()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create you own services and then call them from all the controllers

see [Symfony service container](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can extend ApController controller like this:

```
class ApiController extends DefaultController
{
    public function yourAction()
    {
         $this->getCategoryAction();
    }
}
```

Or even better create a MyClass class  (if getCategoryAction is going to be reused) register as a service

It all depend what you want to achieve at the end